# Can I tell Powershell remote session to deploy from server a to b and from b to c

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

We have a TeamCity machine.
We have a networkshare.
We have "client" server A
We have "target" server B.

The TeamCity machine need to grab a already existing .zip file from the networkshare and move it to server A which again has to forward it to server B.

There is no direct access from teamcity machine to server B. Server A is always the gateway/bridge I have to take.

What is the best approach here to fullfill my task using powershell?

I have already a working version using a powershell filewatcher on server A watching file dumps and moving those files to server B.

I want a technical more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Why 3 close votes? Any statement please?!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "I want a technical more sophisticated solution." but based on your description, the following script will do what you require:

```
$NetworkSourcePath = "\\Network\Path\To\Source.zip"
$ServerA_Destination = "\\ServerA\C$\Path\To\ServerA_Destination.zip"
$ServerB_Destination = "\\ServerB\C$\Path\To\ServerB_Destination.zip"

Copy-Item $NetworkSourcePath $ServerA_Destination

Invoke-Command -ComputerName A -ArgumentList $ServerA_Destination,$ServerB_Destination -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item $ServerA_Destination $ServerB_Destination }
```

Comment: The Filewatcher script is just stupid. Therefore I want a more sophisticated solution. I do not have $ServerA_Destination and $ServerB_Destination as Share available just the source.zip is on a network share.

Comment: How are you transferring the files to ServerB?

Comment: From ServerA to ServerB via msdeploy.exe to a virtual path.